# How to implement a Windows Form in vb2008 in vb6

Tags: winforms, vb6

I have written a Test-Form in vb2008 in order to call it as a mdi-child in vb6:

The code is as followed:
`

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComClass(frmTest.ClassId, frmTest.InterfaceId, frmTest.EventsId)> _
Public Class frmTest
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region "COM-GUIDs"
    Public Const ClassId As String = ""
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = ""
    Public Const EventsId As String = ""
#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

Public Overloads Sub Show(ByVal MDI As Object)
    Me.MdiParent = CType(MDI, System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    Me.Show

End Sub


    Public Sub SomeText(ByVal Text As String)
        MsgBox(Text)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("Test")
    End Sub
End Class
```

`

In vb6, under references I make a reference to the tlb.

So far, so good.

I open a new project and create a new MDI-Form.

```
Private Sub Start_Click(Index As Integer)
   Dim f As New MyTestLibrary.frmTest
   f.Show (Me)

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not work, because it is COM-Component, and an error occurs. Anyone knows a verified way to make a windows .NET form available in VB6 ???

Thank you, in advance.

Stephan

Comment: That can't work of course.  Keep it KISS by exposing a UserControl instead.  Look at the [Interop Forms Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264), tutorial [is here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18954/Interop-Forms-Toolkit-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

- Put your VB 6 in a DLL. Create a public method that invokes a modal dialog from VB 6.
- From your .NET program, reference the DLL built in VB 6 (COM tab)
- Invoke the method. Your VB6 modal form will appear.

However, some things may not work such as some ActiveX controls embedded in the VB 6 code might have problems.